# How can I clear and reload my nrepl session in emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

I am working with emacs and nrepl. How can I do the following:

1. Exit `nrepl` (currently I just kill the buffer)
2. Reload everything I was working with in `nrepl`.

The problem I'm trying to solve by doing this is that when I have loaded an `ns` form and it has an error, I am unable to load the correct code because it keeps giving me the previous error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Exit the nrepl (currently I just kill the buffer)

`M-x nrepl-quit`

> 2) Reload everything in the nrepl. (I have this problem when I haave
>   loaded the ns, and it has an error. Then I am unable to load the
>   correct code, it still keeps giving me the previous error)

You can switch to the buffer and use `C-c C-k` to load the buffer, or just use `C-c C-c` to eval an expression. Another option would be:

```
(use :reload 'my.namespace)
```

in the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Stuart Sierra's [tools](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) for namespace management at the repl, and read the blog [post](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/06/04/clojure-workflow-reloaded) where he explains how to use it effectively. With a little bit of coding discipline, you won't have to exit your nrepl anymore (or less, in any case).
Good luck.