# What is the proper way to shutdown nrepl?

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

How do you gracefully shutdown nrepl in emacs?

swank-clojure was shutdown with a comma and then `sayoonara`, which does not work with nrepl.

Comment: In my experience (on Windows), `M-x nrepl-quit` leaves a Java process running in the background. `(System/exit 0)` quits Java totally but stops Emacs from creating a new NREPL session until you restart it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15701632/271324

Comment: @danlei, perhaps the answer overlaps, but it's a stretch to say it's the same question

Comment: Ballpark: It's not an exact duplicate, but the question I linked to contains your question, and it is anwered there. I didn't vote to close – just left a pointer.

Comment: At least I *think* it is anwered there. Doesn't `nrepl-quit` fit your needs?

Comment: Ah yes... I will mark it as the answer.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`M-x nrepl-quit` works for me. Don't know if there's a shortcut in the repl itself.

Comment: Currently it is called nrepl-close.